# Assign Specific Template for Custom Post slug

Tags: templates, terms

I have been searching since the hours and I stop ... crazy !

Is there a way to assign a template to a "personalized publication" for a particular "term"?

That I have A WPQUERY

```
// Arguments de la requête
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'maisons',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'cat_maisons',
                'terms' => '18'
            ),
        ),
     );
```

I would like to be able to have a permalink to a specific template such as:

**single-maisons-18.php**

Because the permalink always sends me on the template "single-maisons.php"
I tried with the URL Rewriting like here:

but I did not succeed. If someone can help me before I lose all my hair ...

Sorry for my bad English, i'm French…

/* UPDATE */
Information to emphasize, the posts listed have 2 terms of selected
it's a problem ?

[image: Terms...]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) it does not look like there is a way to do this automatically, by post type and taxonomy. But, you could use a page template which you would need to select on every custom post where you want to use the different template.

In the code where you define the custom post type (maisons), add a `'supports'` parameter.

```
register_post_type('maisons',
    array(
        ...
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'page-attributes')
    )
);
```

"Page attributes" will let you use any custom Page templates you have created. You may need to use `unregister_post_type()` and then re-register it to make it work.

For each taxonomy, you can create a template file called for example `"tpl-maison-avec-terrain.php"` with the following code at the top:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Maison+Terrain
 */
```

Then on the Editor screen for each of the posts, you'll see a "Page Template" dropdown where you can choose whichever template you want to use. That may also help because it will allow you to manually decide whether you want to use "maison+terrain" or "vivre a l-horizontal" for posts that have more than one taxonomy assigned.